# Why does `hidden` not override `block` when using classes in a Tailwind CSS rule?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to use conditional classes with the `peer` class in Tailwind CSS to conditionally show or hide an error message. I found a code block in the Tailwind CSS documentation that uses the `block` and `hidden` classes in a specific order, but I'm confused about why the `hidden` class does not override the `block` class as I expected.

I came across the following HTML code in the Tailwind CSS documentation that uses the `peer` class with conditional `block` and `hidden` classes to show or hide an error message based on the state of an input element:

```html
<form>
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="is-dirty peer" required />
  <div class="peer-[.is-dirty]:peer-required:block hidden">
    This field is required.
  </div>
  <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

From what I understand, this code block creates a new class that applies the `block` class to the element if it has the `is-dirty` class and the `required` attribute, and applies then applies the `hidden` class.

However, I'm confused about why the `hidden` class does not override the `block` class as I expected. Specifically, I expected the error message "This field is required." to be hidden if the input element is not both dirty and required, since the `hidden` class appears after the conditional `block` class in the rule.

So my questions are:

- **Why does the hidden class not override the block class as I expected in this rule?**
- **Does the order of the `block` and `hidden` classes in the `peer-[.is-dirty]:peer-required:block hidden` rule matter, and if so, how does it affect the behavior of the rule?**

I would appreciate any insights or explanations you can provide. Thank you!

Note: This code block is from the [Tailwind CSS documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#arbitrary-peers).

Comment: Hidden in this occasion is the default state. If the condition for display block is not met, then the div is going to be hidden.

classes after : are enabled ONLY if the condition before the : is true.

For example on " hover:pr-2 pr-0 " the padding is going to be 0, unless you hover the div. When you hover, it's going to be 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the hidden class not override the block class as I expected in this rule?

For CSS rules with the different [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), a rule with higher specificity will take precedence:

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.block.block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden block">Will be display block</div>
<div class="block hidden">Will be display block</div>
```

The `.block.block` rule has higher specificity and so will override the `.hidden` rule

Extending this concept to Tailwind, the CSS rule generated from the `peer-[.is-dirty]:peer-required:block` class will have higher specificity than the `hidden` class:

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.peer.is-dirty:required ~ .peer-\[\.is-dirty\]\:peer-required\:block {
  display: block;
}
```

So the `peer-[.is-dirty]:peer-required:block` will always override `hidden` as long as the former class would match.

> Does the order of the `block` and `hidden` classes in the `peer-[.is-dirty]:peer-required:block hidden` rule matter, and if so, how does it affect the behavior of the rule?

The `peer-[.is-dirty]:peer-required:block hidden` is not a single "rule", but two different classes, `peer-[.is-dirty]:peer-required:block` and `hidden`. Their order does not matter when declared in any source code.